# DynoTable Prevent Remove Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Actually I have one issue in jQuery DynoTables. Here I am able to add many rows as I want but one more condition I have is while removing the rows it should prevent removing the rows when the row count is 3. If the row count is more than 3 it could be removed but it should prevent after that.

```
<table id="beers">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img class="drag-beer" src="drag.png" alt="click and drag to rearrange" />
            </td>
            <td class="beer">

            </td>
            <td>
                <img class="clone-beer" src="clone.png" alt="Clone Row" />                        
            </td>
            <td>
                <img class="remove-beer" src="remove.png" alt="Remove Row" />
            </td>
        </tr>            
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img class="drag-beer" src="drag.png" alt="click and drag to rearrange" />
            </td>
            <td class="beer">

            </td>
            <td>
                <img class="clone-beer" src="clone.png" alt="Clone Row" />                        
            </td>
            <td>
                <img class="remove-beer" src="remove.png" alt="Remove Row" />
            </td>
        </tr>  
        <tr id="add-beer-template">
            <td>
                <img class="drag-beer" src="drag.png" alt="click and drag to rearrange" />
            </td>
            <td class="beer">
                <!-- Beer text will go here  -->
            </td>
            <td>
                <img class="clone-beer" src="clone.png" alt="Clone Row" />                        
            </td>
            <td>
                <img class="remove-beer" src="remove.png" alt="Remove Row" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

```
$('#beers').dynoTable({
            removeClass      : '.remove-beer',       // Custom remover class name in beers table
            cloneClass       : '.clone-beer',        // Custom cloner class name in beers table
            lastRowRemovable : false,
            // addRowTemplateClass: '.otherAddDocRow', //Custom id for beer row template
            lastRowRemovable : false,
            limitRows:3,
            onRowRemove: function(){
                // Check if it's not the last row before removing
                if ($('#uploadAdditionalDoc tbody tr').length > 2) {
                    updateRowState();
                }
            },
            onRowClone: function(){
                clearAlertMsg();
                updateRowState();
                $('.otherAddDocRow').each(function(index){
                    recordNo = index + 1;
                });
                console.log(recordNo);
                // Blank Row Values
                $('.documentType').eq(recordNo - 1).val('');
                $('.uploadedFile').eq(recordNo - 1).val('');
                clearUpload($('.uploadFile').eq(recordNo - 1).attr('id'));
                $('.document_alert').eq(recordNo - 1).html('');
                // uploadAdditionalFiles(); //for file boxes
            },
        });
```